# PHP not executing after include in Joomla 3.5

Tags: php, joomla

I have the following code and everytime I try to echo something above my include it doesn't work, seems like the 'include' is breakng my code.

PD:For more information my file is inside /my_main_folder/administrator/components/com_helloworld/

```
<?php 
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../' ));  

include(JPATH_BASE.'/libraries/loader.php');

$name = "a";
$username = "b";
$password = "jhvv";
$email = "arcghh";

addJoomlaUser($name, $username, $password, $email);

function addJoomlaUser($name, $username, $password, $email) {
    jimport('joomla.user.helper');
    $data = array(
        "name"=>$name,
        "username"=>$username,
        "password"=>$password,
        "password2"=>$password,
        "email"=>$email,
        "block"=>0,
        "groups"=>array("1","2")
    );

    $user = new JUser;
    //Write to database
    if(!$user->bind($data)) {
        throw new Exception("Could not bind data. Error: " . $user->getError());
    }
    if (!$user->save()) {
        throw new Exception("Could not save user. Error: " . $user->getError());
    }

    return $user->id;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to redefine a constant that is already defined, with:

```
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../' ));
```

This is probably what is breaking your code. See [Joomla constants](https://docs.joomla.org/Constants)

Comment: Good point, didn't know about that. But anyways even if I jus write my include like " include('../../../libraries/loader.php'); " it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your relative path actually works, most likely you are running into some ModSecurity rule - the `../...` is looked at with scrutiny by any server nowadays, because of the possibility of reading critical server files.

Try using the actual physical path instead of relative paths...